# AJAX, PHP returning undefined or nothing

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I have 3 files.

1.) The file for displaying it

```
<div id="tweet">

    </div>
```

this is where it should be displayed.

2.)the php file that gets the data from the database

```
 function ajaxGetTweets()
  {
    $stmtSelectTweets = $this->db->prepare('SELECT * FROM tweets');
    $stmtSelectTweets->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $stmtSelectTweets->execute();
    $data = $stmtSelectTweets->fetchAll();
    print_r(json_encode($data));
  }
```

this function return the result in json, i got the right format when i use print_r

3.) the js file for ajax

```
    $( document ).ready(function() {

    $.get("homescreen/ajaxGetTweets", function( o )
    {
        for(var i = 0; i < o.length; i++)
        {
            $("#tweet").append("<div>"+o[i].tweet+"</div>");
        }
    }, "json");

});
```

when leaving the "json" at the end of the $.get function i got a result in my div as undefined, when using "json", i got nothing.

in the console i got a warning like:

> Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of
>   its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help,
>   check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

```
Output: <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Twitter</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/mvc_tut/public/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/mvc_tut/public/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/mvc_tut/public/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>

  <div id="header">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="http://localhost/mvc_tut/index">Startseite<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="http://localhost/mvc_tut/ueberuns">Über uns</a></li>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
      </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
  </div>
  <div id="content">
ERROR
  </div>
  <div id="footer">
    Footer
  </div>
</body>
</html>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Twitter</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/mvc_tut/public/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/mvc_tut/public/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/mvc_tut/public/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/mvc_tut/views/homescreen/js/homescreen.js"></script>

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>

  <div id="header">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="http://localhost/mvc_tut/homescreen">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="http://localhost/mvc_tut/notifications">Notifications</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://localhost/mvc_tut/messages">Messages</a></li>
          </ul>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
          <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Tweet</button>
          </form>
          <form class="navbar-form" action="homescreen/logout" method="post">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Logout</button>
          </form>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
      </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
  </div>
  <div id="content">
<div class="container-fluid">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="row">

      </div>
      <div class="row">

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <form class="form-control" id="tweetInsert"  action="http://localhost/mvc_tut/homescreen/ajaxInsertTweet" method="post">
        <textarea name="tweetText" rows="3" cols="40"></textarea>
        <button type="submit" name="submitTweet">Tweet</button>
      </form>
      <div class="row">

        <div id="tweet">

        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="row">

      </div>
      <div class="row">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer">
    Footer
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: in the PHP part, I think you either print_r($data) or you echo(json_encode($data)); not both. do you agree?

Comment: sorry this print_r was for debugging issues, i changed it to json_encode($data)

Comment: can you please console.log "o"? $.get("homescreen/ajaxGetTweets", function( o ) { console.log("O: " + o); ..................... }

Comment: i dont know why but it does nothing in the console. so it doesnt get into this function, but when i leave the json at the end of this function it will reply undefined

Comment: try this and check the console please:  `$.get("homescreen/ajaxGetTweets", function( o ) { console.log("Output: " + o); });`

Comment: firebug-lite.js:11883 Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/. 

this is the only thing that is inside the console

Comment: something's wrong. can you paste the previous code I suggested directly into your browser's console?

Comment: i posted the code above... i come into my error_controller, but i dont no why, this is just happening, because i force the browser to get into the homescreen_controller/ajaxGetTweets_function, normaly this function shoul get called when in the homescreen... and then there is no second console log

Comment: it is outputting an entire html page?

Comment: yes, it does output an entire html page, when you look at the post below i posted the output of print_r(json_encode($data)), maybe you see if there is something wrong

Comment: I looked at it, it looks fine... I really can't guess what's going on. Sorry.

Comment: @GrafiCode hey, the equivalent for this function would be $.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  url: "homescreen/ajaxGetTweets",
  async: true,
  success: function(data)
  {
    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
    {
      $("#tweet").append("<div>"+data[i].tweet+"</div>");
    }
  }
  });

Comment: @GrafiCodeStudio I solved it, i added a exit; after echo json_encode($data), because it does echo the json format and the whle page, i guess its because the index function gets called, but now it only echo the json file, so it works fine

Answer (score 0):

Let me rephrase it a little:

```
$.getJSON("homescreen/ajaxGetTweets", function(o) {
    var h="";
    for(var i=0; i<o.length; i++) h+="<div>"+o[i].tweet+"</div>";
    $("#tweet").html(h);
});
```

This way it's better to understand and a lot faster (because you only write the content once, allowing the browser to render it only 1 time).  But your version should also have worked; if it didn't, maybe we need to check out the structure of your JSON to see if that field really exists, etc.

If the returned JSON is not an array, for example, maybe you'll need a different *for* syntax to walk along it.

**UPDATE**

*GrafiCode Studio* was right! You should change the "print_r" to a plain "print" when you return the JSON.  Didn't spot that one!  He should get the points...